# jquery click event

Tags: jquery

can we use more than one click event in the Jquery
as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
...........click(function(){
...........click(function(){
});

$(this).hide();
});
});
```

pls help me

i wrap the code due to less space for the code

```
$('#togglebutton1').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':visible')){ 
          $('#bio>div,#heading2,#heading3 ').hide(); 
          $('#bio>div:first').show();
          $('p:first').toggle(
             function() { 
                 $(this).animate({ 'height': '+=15px' }, '1000', 'linear'); 
             }, 
             function() {
                 $(this).animate({ 'height': '-=15px' }, '1000', 'swing');
             }
          );
          $(this).val('ShowImage');
       }else { 
         $(' #bio > div,#heading2,#heading3 ').show(); 
         $(this).val('HideImage'); 
       } 
}); 
$('#bio h3').click(function() { 
     $(this).next().animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce'); }); 
});
```

Comment: can you be more specific on what you really want to achieve?... because everyone is confused?!... why are you putting `click()` s inside ` .click() ` ? anything I missed?

Comment: bcoz i want to add two different button for hide image and show image.

Comment: @picnic4u: That's still not hyper-clear, but if you want to attach the same handler to two different buttons, that's no problem, see [yuval's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947617/jquery-click-event/2947672#2947672)

Comment: i m doing so but image hiding is working but after that the button name is also change but when i click agin to show image it's not  working?
the code is following

Comment: i wrap the code due to less space for the code
$('#togglebutton1').click(function() {if ($(this).is(':visible')){ $('#bio>div,#heading2,#heading3 ').hide(); $('#bio>div:first').show();$('p:first').toggle(function() {
$(this).animate({ 'height': '+=15px' }, '1000', 'linear');
}, function() {$(this).animate({ 'height': '-=15px' }, '1000', 'swing');});$(this).val('ShowImage');}else {
$(' #bio > div,#heading2,#heading3 ').show();
$(this).val('HideImage');
 }
});
  $('#bio h3').click(function() {
  $(this).next().animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
            });
        });

Comment: @picnic4u - I added your code above for better view...

Comment: @picnic4u - is your image in `p:first` ?

Comment: no my image in div and div has a id=bio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have meant running the same function on several different elements.
This can be done as such:

```
$("#mydiv1, #mydiv2, #mydiv3").click(function(){
    //some code
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can bind multiple handlers to the `click` event of the same element:

```
$('#myElementID').click(function() {
    // do something here
})

// Elsewhere (presumably)
$('#myElementID').click(function() {
    // do something else here
})
```

Provided the first handler that gets called doesn't stop the event (via [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or by returning `false` from the handler), the next one will get called. jQuery guarantees that handlers will get called in the order in which they're registered (even when the browser doesn't). (This is covered in the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) docs, but applies to the `click` function as well, as `click` is just a shorthand version of `bind` for the `click` event.)

Comment: what's the point of multiple click, it will boil down to same things. The OP basically means multiple events.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Usually this comes up when you have disparate parts of the code that both need to hook the event, which either don't know about each other or which shouldn't be inter-dependent. It's the whole point of DOM2 handlers (the `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` browsers provide that jQuery uses under the covers). The previous "DOM0" mechanism, `onclick` attributes, only allowed a single handler, which was limiting. Re what the OP means, that's for them to clarify. What they've *said* is "multiple click events".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bind more than one click event. Have a look at the jQuery "bind" method.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** for that.

**Example:**

```
$('#foo').bind('click mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

As can be seen, three evens are attached eg `click mouseenter mouseleave` to the element with `id` set to `#foo`.

Comment: *"More than one click event"*, not more than one event.

Comment: @Crowder: `click` is also an event, right? Isn't `bind` used for multiple events?

Comment: @Web Logic: Yes, it is, and that's cool. It just doesn't answer the question the OP had (at least, as far as I can tell what the question is).

Comment: what's the point of multiple click, it will boil down to same things. The OP basically means multiple events.

Comment: @Sarfraz: See my response to your identical comment on my answer.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You are right, but i still suspect, OP basically means more than one event, let's see what he has to say :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can... jQuery is good on chaining...

but I think you should clarify more on your question on what really you want to achieve... so that we can suggest more and better idea.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // unbind default click event
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();
        // or
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.function1();
        $this.function2();
        $this.function3();
    });
});
```